# Inserting thousands of JSONs into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm sure this is probably a fairly simple query for most but I'm quite new to Python and thus Pandas as well. Ultimately, I have thousands of JSON files in a folder that I would like to get into a dataframe. This is the code I'm currently using but unfortunately, it is brutally slow. My guess is because I'm opening every file and processing before moving to the next, this is causing a lag. Seems it would be better to get all the JSON together before loading into a dataframe but I'm not sure.

```
df = p.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("log_test/*.json"):
    with io.open(f,"rb") as infile:
        binstr = infile.read()
    objlist = loads(binstr.decode("utf-8"))
    temp = p.json_normalize(objlist['data'])
    df = df.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
```

I have tried adding the JSON file values into a dictionary but I can't seem to correctly normalize as I only need the data at the data level within the JSON.

```
resultdict = {}
for f in glob.glob("log_test/*.json"):
    with io.open(f,"rb") as infile:
        resultdict[f] = json.load(infile)
```

Here is structure of the sample data:

```
{ "type" : "MTA", "data" : [{"foo":"bar","foo":"bar","foo":"bar"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to speed things up:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        x = json.load(f)
    return pd.json_normalize(x['data'])


with ThreadPoolExecutor() as ex:
    frames = list(ex.map(read_file, glob.glob('log_test/*.json')))
df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
```

Example setup:

```py
for i in range(1000):
    d = {
        'type': 'MTA',
        'data': pd.DataFrame(
            np.random.randint(0, 10, (50, 10)),
            columns=list('abcdefghij')).to_dict(orient='records')
    }
    with open(f'tests/foo-{i:03d}.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(d, f)
```

Then timing the above shows roughly 1.85s to read and concatenate the 1000 files.

**alternatively**, you can just merge the lists and then do a single `pd.json_normalize()`:

```py
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return json.load(f)['data']

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as ex:
    merged_data = [e for lst in ex.map(read_file, glob.glob('tests/*.json')) for e in lst]

df2 = pd.json_normalize(merged_data)
```

This goes about twice as fast on the example data above (859 ms). But it assumes that your JSON files are each a list of dicts.